# Add TabIndex to buttons built by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, set, tabindex

I have buttons built with JavaScript and want to add TabIndex for keyboard accessibility. I added accesskey values in this code and in this code:

```
button41 = new ObjButton('button41',null,679,0,53,32,1,54,'div')
button41.setImages('images/0807_help.jpg','images/0807_help_over.jpg','images/0807_help_over.jpg')
button41.onUp = button41onUp
button41.hasOnUp = true
button41.capture=4
button41.setAccessKey(2)
button41.setTabIndex(2)
button41.build()
```

But when I tried to add TabIndex, the TabIndex number didn't work. Any suggestions? Here is the script:

```
function ObjButtonBuild() {
    this.css = buildCSS(this.name,this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h,this.v,this.z)
    this.div = '<' + this.divTag + ' id="'+this.name+'" style="text-indent:0;"></' + this.divTag + '>\n'
    this.divInt = '<a name="'+this.name+'anc" href="javascript:void(null)"'
    if(this.accessKeyValue && this.accessKeyValue!=null) {
        this.divInt+=' accessKey='+this.accessKeyValue+' ';
    }
    if( this.altName )
        this.divInt += ' title="'+this.altName+'"'
    else if( this.altName != null )
        this.divInt += ' title=""'
        this.divInt += '><img name="'+this.name+'Img" src="'+this.imgOffSrc
    if( this.altName )
        this.divInt += '" alt="'+this.altName
    else if( this.altName != null )
        this.divInt += '" alt="'
        this.divInt += '" width='+this.w+' height='+this.h+' border=0'
    if( !is.ns4 ) 
        this.divInt += ' style="cursor:pointer"'
        this.divInt += '></a>'
}
```

Comment: jQuery would make your code much, much nicer.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be building your elements that way. Use `document.createElement()` instead:

```
var el = document.createElement("a");
if (el){
    el.name = "foo";
    el.href = "somepage.htm";
    el.tabIndex = 3;
}
```

You can also do it this way:

```
var el = document.createElement("a");
if (el){
    el.setAttribute("class", "someclass");
    el.setAttribute("name", "foo");  
    el.setAttribute("href", "somepage.htm");
    el.setAttribute("tabIndex", "3");
}
```

You can also use jQuery for this:

```
var el = $("<a>", { name : "foo", href : "somepage.htm", tabIndex : "6" });
```